# Changing color of a row in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to change "selector" color in drop-down list?

```
 <select name="select" style="background-color: #ff0000">
 <option style="background-color: #ff0000" value="1">Red</option>
 <option style="background-color: #ffffff" value="2">Green</option>
 <option style="background-color: #0000ff" value="3">Blue</option>
 </select>
```

I tried in above style but it didn't worked. I know with JavaScript getting `document.getElementById('text').style.color='red'` can set the color.

But is it possible in HTML to set the colors?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a cross compatible way of accomplishing this without the aid of Javascript. i.e. Styling each option value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Edit: also works in IE6

Comment: Did you click on the drop-down and select different values?  You should get a red "green", for example.

Answer (score 6):

To preserve the background color of the selected item (which I believe is what you're after) add the following `onchange` code:

```
<select name="select" style="background-color: #ff0000" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor = this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor;">
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/LD8Dx/

Answer (score 2):

its work correctly in many browsers.
I didnt see any problem with this HTML.

Comment: The problem is when you select an item, the bgcolor of the drop down box stays as the original colour. Shadow Wizards solution is correct.