# Change dropdown colour on selection

Tags: drop-down-menu, colors, background

I have a dropdown which has different colours for each option, however when the option is chosen I would like the select background to change to the color I have chosen.

I have found an answer to this query, however this uses inline styles and I would like to use my external CSS.

[Changing color of a row in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930539/changing-color-of-a-row-in-dropdown-list)

[**See My JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/LD8Dx/)

```
<select name="select" style="background-color: #ff0000" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor = this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor;">
 <option style="background-color: #ff0000" value="1">Red</option>
 <option style="background-color: #00ff00" value="2">Green</option>
 <option style="background-color: #0000ff" value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use external css, then

```
<select name="select" class="Red" onchange="this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
  <option class="Red" value="1">Red</option>
  <option class="Green" value="2">Green</option>
  <option class="Blue" value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LD8Dx/74/)